# How to implement this test on prototype of String object?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

How to implement this valid function?

I want to implement a test function that returns true or false,

example :   'any-string-1'.valid('!empty'):

this is my valid.js file

```
function valid(str) {
  if (
    typeof str == "undefined" ||
    !str ||
    str === "" ||
    str.length < 10 ||
    !/[^\s]/.test(str) ||
    /^.*-s/i.test(str)
  ) {
    return true;
  } else if (str.length > 30) {
    return false;
  }
}
module.exports = valid;
```

Comment: Please describe a bit more the problem, for example, are you using Jest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Jest, you can use `toBe`:

```
const emptyStr = '';
const str = 'some-str';
    
expect(Boolean(emptyStr.length)).toBe(false); // it's empty, it's false because length is 0;
    
expect(str.length > 30).toBe(false); // it's false because length is not greather than 30;
    
expect(str.length < 10).toBe(true); // it's true because length is lower than 10;
```

Comment: It should be a prototype function of the String object. the valid function should return true or false